# R: Scraping aspx from doPostBack

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape [this page](http://www.smv.gob.pe/Frm_ValorCuotaDetalle_V2.aspx?in_ac_pre_ope=A&tip_fon_desc=TODAS&in_ad_fecha=24/12/2019) to download the file in excel.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE6yI.png)
I've been trying this until now but it doesn't help me:

```
library(rvest)  

url_smv<-"http://www.smv.gob.pe/Frm_ValorCuotaDetalle_V2.aspx?in_ac_pre_ope=A&tip_fon_desc=TODAS&in_ad_fecha=24/12/2019"
html_nodes(read_html(url_smv), css = "#cbExcel")
download.file(url_smv,destfile ="s.xls",mode="w")
df<-read_excel("s.xls",skip = 14) #it doesn't work for me
```

This only downloads the page in html format. 
Idk how to get the url that contains the java application (javascript:__doPostBack('cbExcel','')) to download Excel

.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the URL information where the file is stored

[image]

Once you do that you can use `download.file`

```
download.file('http://www.smv.gob.pe/Frm_ValorCuotaDetalle_V2.aspx?in_ac_pre_ope=A&tip_fon_desc=TODAS&in_ad_fecha=24%2f12%2f2019', 'TEMP.xls')
```